# Switching to Mongoose, should I not use the request client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im creating a MEAN stack app based loosely around the demo found here: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

Im new to mongo but want to use Mongoose on the server-side and noticed it currently talks to the database using the request client:

code: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/server/lib/mongo-strategy.js

```
var rest = require('request');
...
MongoDBStrategy.prototype.query = function(query, done) {
  query.apiKey = this.apiKey;
  var request = rest.get(this.baseUrl, { qs: query, json: {} }, function(err, response, body) {
    done(err, body);
  });
};
```

The server is also configured in a way that it proxies calls to the mongolab REST API (found here: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/server/lib/mongo-proxy.js).

Im not really sure if there's a specific reason the app uses request instead of mongod native or mongoose, but in order to start using mongoose, do I simply remove the request client and start using mongoose? And will that interfere with the proxy at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, with mongoose you should definitely use the native driver.

In the angular-app project you mentioned the mongolab API is proxied all the way down to the client code:

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/vendor/mongolab/mongolab-resource.js

The advantage here I suppose would be that it saves you the trouble of having to write your own express API layer because your client is effectively just using mongolab's API structure directly. But I suppose this comes at the cost of flexibility and performance.

The native driver can also do much more than the REST API. Apart from better performance, if your query returns large data sets the native driver offers you things like [cursors](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html) and [streams](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream). With the REST client your query results would be paginated.

Unortunately if you've built your app very closely to how angular-app is structured, moving to mongoose probably wouldn't be an easy swap, it would mean model level code changes in the client and server.

For good mongoose+angular examples however, meanjs.org has a nice reference implementation that you might be find useful:
https://github.com/meanjs/mean

It also has a fantastic yeoman generator for generating projects, models, routes, etc:
http://meanjs.org/generator.html

**Edit:** Another good reason to avoid REST is that mongodb doesn't provide this API out of the box, so you couldn't run tests using a localhost mongodb without also hosting your local REST service in between the two. In fact you can then only run your app against mongo providers that offer this API, such as mongolab so if you ever wanted to try out mongodb's MMS or switch to a different provider like compose.io you'd probably have to switch back to the native driver anyway.

Comment: It is still early to where I would be fine with rewriting parts of it to have it work the way it should... Would you recommend I scratch the mongolab resource on the client side, and the proxy and REST API on the server side...? or start from scratch using meanjs?

Comment: Meanjs appears to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, the mongolab resource on the client side seems to be the only good reason for why angular-app would proxy the rest api on the server side. I would say go all native+mongoose or go all rest+proxy.